# When a Node.js process can exit() directly without triggering other signal events (uncaughtException, SIGINT, SIGTERM...)

Tags: node.js, exit

I work on an application with a REDIS data store. To maintain the data integrity I would like to cleanup the store on process shutdown.

I created a function handler and bind it (with process.on()) to signal events: uncaughtException, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT and it works well (CTRL+C, process killing, exception, ...).

But I've read that in certain conditions the process can exit directly without triggering the other signal events.

The problem in this particular case is that process.on('exit') handler can only process synchronous tasks.

I made different test to try to kill the process in different ways. 
And (except with SIGTERM on Windows) I wasn't able to identify the case where process.on('exit') is triggered directly without SIGINT, SIGTERM or other event firing.

So my question is (on Linux system), under what conditions the process can exit directly without firing on of this event: http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_signal_events ?

Comment: Good first question, welcome to SO : ), also, where did you read about other conditions? It could be good starting point for research.

Comment: On this comment at least the author says: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-redis/pull/15

_"I didn't manage to do the exit cleanup correctly, **so after normal exit**, rooms are still filled up with the same (now unexisting) socket ids. Quitting with Ctrl+C or the kill signal should work as expected."_

So maybe I can ask directly to him what a "normal exit" means.

Comment: That would be a good idea, I don t see how he can "exit normally" without the code going in one of the process event...

Comment: The "normal exit" was for first and last point of your list. You answer seems complete for me. Could be interesting if anyone has something to add to your list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now, reading the [docume](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html)[ntation](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) and doing some [re](https://www.google.fr/search?q=node+js+exit+-connection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=nts&gfe_rd=cr&ei=IeIjVOOUMMHQ8ge4qYHYDQ)[search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=node+js+close+-connection&btnG=Rechercher&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=nts&gfe_rd=cr), it seems there is only four way a node.js app exit:

- `process.exit()`, which is handled by [`process.on('exit')`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit)
- Receiving a *nix signal, which can be handled by [process.on('signal_name')`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_signal_events)
- Having a exception going back to the event loop, handled by [`process.on('UncaughtException')`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)
- The computer being plugged out, destroyed, the node.js binary blowing up, or a SIGKILL/kill -9, and there is no handling to that.

It usually happen someone don t understand the error message from a uncaughtException, and mistakenly believe it is "something else" that killed node.js.

Comment: That's not quite correct.  When a process is actually terminated directly by a signal (as with SIGABRT, as a common example), there is no opportunity to handle the signal.  The program can choose to handle the signal and then exit, but from the operating system perspective (as reported by the wait(2) family), the signal did not terminate the process -- it just exited normally.

Comment: @DavePacheco: But the event `process.on('SIGABRT')` will still get executed first, even if the OS think the program exited normally.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed.  I just meant to point out that Node programs can exit as a result of a signal without having executed a handler (if none was registered).  Rereading your post, I see that may be what you meant as well.